# How to register non-browser based app for OAuth API?

Tags: oauth

For example: http://www.behance.net/dev/register
requires website name for registering desktop app, but what could possibly be the website for such app??

How to register such non-browser based app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL requires credentials so I cannot see exactly what they're requesting, but it probably wants the application's [redirection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2).

In OAuth, client apps not only reside on a resource owner's device, but they must also operate a server that knows how to participate in one or more of the OAuth grant processes.  The point of requiring a redirection endpoint is so the access token can be transmitted from the authorization server to the client app's server without exposing it to the other applications running on the resource owner's device.